# Given $n \tan b = \tan a$ and $ m \sin b = \sin a$ to find out the value of $\frac{m^2 - 1}{n^2-1}$

Tags: trigonometry

Given $n \tan b = \tan a$ and $ m \sin b = \sin a$ to find out the value of $\frac{m^2 - 1}{n^2-1}$

My attempt:

$n \tan b = \tan a$

$$=> n = \frac{\sin a \cos b}{\sin b \cos a}$$

Given

$$ m \sin b = \sin a$$
$$ => \frac mn = \frac{\cos a}{\cos b}$$

I don't know where to go from here please help

Comment: how much are you sure that $n\neq 1$???

Comment: The answer is $\cos^2 a$.

Comment: Yes that is the answer can you please post the solution #PGFTricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{m^2-1}{n^2-1}=\frac{\frac{\sin^2a}{\sin^2b}-1}{\frac{\tan^2a}{\tan^2b}-1}$

$=\frac{\sin^2a-\sin^2b}{\sin^2b}.\frac{\tan^2b}{\tan^2a-\tan^2b}$

$=\frac{\sin^2a-\sin^2b}{\sin^2b}.\frac{\sin^2b}{\cos^2b}.\frac{1}{\tan^2a-\tan^2b}$

$=\frac{\sin^2a-\sin^2b}{\cos^2b}.\frac{1}{\frac{\sin^2a}{\cos^2a}-\frac{\sin^2b}{\cos^2b}}$

$=\frac{\sin^2a-\sin^2b}{\cos^2b}.\frac{1}{\frac{\sin^2a\cos^2b-\sin^2b\cos^2a}{\cos^2a\cos^2b}}$

$=(\cos^2a)(\sin^2a-\sin^2b).\big(\frac{1}{\sin^2a\cos^2b-\sin^2b\cos^2a}\big)$

$=(\cos^2a)(\sin^2a-\sin^2b).\big(\frac{1}{\sin^2a(1-\sin^2b)-\sin^2b(1-\sin^2a)}\big)$

$=(\cos^2a)(\sin^2a-\sin^2b).\big(\frac{1}{\sin^2a-\sin^2a\sin^2b-\sin^2b+\sin^2a\sin^2b}\big)$

$=(\cos^2a)(\sin^2a-\sin^2b).(\frac{1}{\sin^2a-\sin^2b})$

$=\cos^2a$

Answer (score 1):

Let us eliminate $b$

We have  $\displaystyle\tan b=\frac{\tan a}n$  and $\displaystyle\sin b=\frac{\sin a}m$

As $\displaystyle \csc^2b-\cot^2b=1,$

$$\frac{m^2}{\sin^2a}-\frac{n^2}{\tan^2a}=1\iff m^2-n^2\cos^2a=\sin^2a$$

$$\iff m^2=n^2\cos^2a+1-\cos^2a\iff m^2-1=\cos^2a(n^2-1)\iff \cos^2a=\frac{m^2-1}{n^2-1}$$

Comment: @user2189524, I think this is how the problem came into being.We can try eliminate $a$ to create another such problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

> [image]

LaTeX Code:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,cancel,xcolor}
\renewcommand\CancelColor{\color{red}}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\begin{align*}
\frac{m^2-1}{n^2-1}
&=
\frac{\left(\frac{\sin a}{\sin b}\right)^2 -1}{\left(\frac{\tan a}{\tan b}\right)^2 -1}\\
&=
\frac{\sin^2 a -\sin^2 b}{\sin^2 b}\times\frac{\tan^2 b}{\tan^2 a -\tan^2 b}\\
&=
\frac{\sin^2 a -\sin^2 b}{\bcancel{\sin^2 b}}\times\frac{\bcancel{\sin^2 b}}{\cancel{\cos^2 b}}\times\frac{\cos^2 a\times \cancel{\cos^2 b}}{\sin^2 a\times\cos^2 b -\sin^2 b\times\cos^2 a}\\
&=
\cos^2 a\times\frac{\sin^2 a -\sin^2 b}{\sin^2 a\times\cos^2 b -\sin^2 b\times\cos^2 a}\\
&=
\cos^2 a\times\frac{(\sin a -\sin b)\times(\sin a +\sin b)}{(\sin a\times\cos b -\sin b\times\cos a)\times(\sin a\times\cos b +\sin b\times\cos a)}\\
&=
\cos^2 a\times\frac{2\cos\frac{a+b}{2}\sin\frac{a-b}{2}\times2\sin\frac{a+b}{2}\cos\frac{a-b}{2}}{\sin (a-b) \times \sin(a+b)}\\
&=
\cos^2 a\times\frac{2\sin\frac{a+b}{2}\cos\frac{a+b}{2}\times2\sin\frac{a-b}{2}\cos\frac{a-b}{2}}{\sin (a-b) \times \sin(a+b)}\\
&=
\cos^2 a\times\frac{\bcancel{\sin (a-b)} \times \cancel{\sin(a+b)}}{\bcancel{\sin (a-b)} \times \cancel{\sin(a+b)}}\\
&=
\cos^2 a
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```